# Custom String Method Validation JSR303 SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a REST-Api where I want to validate the parameters on method Level. With @Valid and a custom object where validation annotations are inside, it works fine, but it fails, if I use a String and write the annotations directly into the method signiture.

## My validator

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{3,128}$")
public @interface CustomValidator{

    public abstract String message() default "Custom Message"

    public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<?>[] payload() default {};
}
```

## My controller class

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    ...
}
```

## What works but is not so nice Code Style

```
@Data
public class FoobarForm{

    @NotNull
    @CustomValidator 
    String foobar;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{bar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Bank checkFoobar(@Valid @CustomValidator @PathVariable String foobar) {
```

## What I want

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{bar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Bank checkIban(@Validated @NotNull @CustomValidator @PathVariable String foobar) {
```

As you can see, I want to validate a String parameter on method Level with a custom Validator. But that does not work. If I put an invalid argument in the method, it passes and the validation is never performed.

---

Of course I can check the Regex in another way since it is a path variable, but I have the same scenario at other Methods and want to have a general Solution for this problem.

Info:
I currently use Spring Version: 4.0.7

Comment: Take a look at HandlerMethodInvoker, ModelAttributeMethodProcessor and DataBinder#validate classes. Do you see any possible solutions to hook into spring validation logic during data binding? I would recommed to stick with the "form" solution since it is very simple and straightforward.

Comment: @Ivan: Sorry, I don't get your point. I read the JavaDoc of those classes, but i don't have any ideas. Can you provide me another hint?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I ment look into sources.. Listed classes are responsible for data binding and validation (which you are interested in), so you can verify by yourself the logic - just search for Valid and PathVariable annotation usages. Then you will be able to answer your own question :)